# Android Phone Dialer App

Tags: android

I'm making a Dialer and I want to search the contacts by name.
But since the Dialer accepts only numbers, how should I search for JOHN by entering the number 5-6-4-6? Are there any existing methods to do so in android?

Answer (score 0):

If this number 5-6-4-6 exists in your contacst than you can use Content uri and hpone uri to lookup for this number and you can compare it with the fetched results...

You can fetch all the contacts and you get the name by comparing this number an d with the fetched numbers from the andorid conatcts api.

```
public void fetchContacts() {

    String phoneNumber = null;
    String email = null;

    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

    Uri EmailCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
    String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);  

    // Loop for every contact in the phone
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME ));

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                output.append("\n First Name:" + name);

                // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                    output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);

                }

                phoneCursor.close();

                // Query and loop for every email of the contact
                Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI,    null, EmailCONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA));

                    output.append("\nEmail:" + email);

                }

                emailCursor.close();
            }

            output.append("\n");
        }

        outputText.setText(output);
    }
}
```

}

this [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/) may help you..

there are various ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assign each letter a numeric code as per numeric keypad with letters.
e.g.
assign 2 to a b & c
assign 3 to d e & f and so on.
Then modify your search accordingly.